# Ignoring whitespace when using mongodb find query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the following mongodb code that works in returning a group name (regardless of case)

```
code = "group1";

let group: any = await this.groupModel.findOne({
  name: { $regex: code, $options: "i" },
});
```

However, some of the group names in my db have spaces e.g - "group 1", and my code variable I am passing in, will always have no spaces.

Is there a way to ignore any spaces in a mongodb find, so if my code variable is "group1", it will still return group names called 'group 1' or 'group1'?

Comment: I think you'd have to have the application manually do that when constructing the query (make a `$or` query).  But doing that and/or using a regex to do case insensitive string matching for what should otherwise be an equality match seems like it may be less performant and scalable in the long term.  Might consider updating the existing data now and forcing consistency when writing data going forward to save you some performance headaches in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `?` to make the space `\\s` character **optional** and find all the documents that either `group1` or `group 1` like below-

```
code = "group\\s?1";

let group: any = await this.groupModel.findOne({
  name: { $regex: code, $options: "i" },
});
```

*In **MongoDB** I think one way to ignore space is possible but that is on `patterns` not on **values***, **See**: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#ignore-white-spaces-in-pattern